# can't connect to mikrotik via Winbox or Http

Tags: router, mikrotik, connection-refused, pptp-client

We have a Mikrotik RB 750GL and I can't connect to it via Winbox or Http.

There is a PPTP connection (Running) between us (On Internet), That RB is PPTP Client.

Winbox stops on retrieving preferences and then disconnect. and Http webpage doesn't load. But I can connect to it via SSH or Telnet remotely and ping it!

and a local client can connect via Winbox or Http.

also I can't conncet to DVR (which connected to that RB).

None of these solutions work for me:

-Frameware Upgrade
-RouterOS Update
-Try L2TP Conncection
-Change MTU
-Change MRRU
-Another Winbox Version
-disable all Firewall Rules
-RB Client Reset Configuration(!)
-secure mode Winbox
-IP>Services: port and address

I need your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be mss problem; as in Tunnels this is most common problem.
Please make sure your packages are Clamped like this:

> Put these rules on top on the mangle table.

```
 ip firewall mangle add chain=forward action=change-mss new-mss=1440 tcp-flags=syn protocol=tcp out-interface=all-ppp tcp-mss=1441-65535 

 ip firewall mangle add chain=forward action=change-mss new-mss=1390 tcp-flags=syn protocol=tcp in-interface=all-ppp tcp-mss=1391-65535
```

> Here is the same rules for Input and Output (which affects mikrotik itself)

```
 ip firewall mangle add chain=input action=change-mss new-mss=1440 tcp-flags=syn protocol=tcp out-interface=all-ppp tcp-mss=1441-65535 

 ip firewall mangle add chain=input action=change-mss new-mss=1390 tcp-flags=syn protocol=tcp in-interface=all-ppp tcp-mss=1391-65535

 ip firewall mangle add chain=output action=change-mss new-mss=1440 tcp-flags=syn protocol=tcp out-interface=all-ppp tcp-mss=1441-65535 

 ip firewall mangle add chain=output action=change-mss new-mss=1390 tcp-flags=syn protocol=tcp in-interface=all-ppp tcp-mss=1391-65535
```

Comment: This mss issue might be on PPTP server as well, so check the server mss config too.

Comment: OMG Thank you so much ! Still I can't connect to the router via winbox or http but Now I can connect to my DVR !!! so do you think is there another value for mss to connect to router?

Comment: just added 2 more rules for the Input chain which should fix it for the mikrotik itself.
Please make make it as answered if it works!

Comment: I can't make three of them and errors appear "Couldn't add New Mangle Rule - tcp mss clamping not  possible in prerouting and input chains.". unfortunately they aren't usefull. any Other idea?! but I'm happy to connect my DVR.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked `IP -> Services` ; Winbox service may be configured on another port or be set to authorize limited addresses.

> If this is the case, here is how you can reset it to default.

`ip service set address=0.0.0.0/0 port=8291 [find name ~"winbox"] disabled=no`

Comment: Thank you but I have checked this before and there is no problem with IP>Services . any other solution?

Comment: There might be a firewall problem/setting in your ISP which deny connections except working ones(ssh, telnet, ping).
Have you checked it from another remote connection? (from Internet somewhere else)

Comment: Do you Think is it possible to filter packets in a PPTP or L2TP Tunnel? I don't think so. anyway I think it's a firewall problem but Where!? I checked every rules. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

A bit late joining the party here, but I had a similar problem.

Logged on to WinBox via MAC address, opened a terminal and then typed in:

```
export file="name-your-file-here"
```

Open that with text editor and then searched for WinBox.

Turns out the WinBox port had been changed.

Comment: I couldn't connect via MAC address because that was a remote router. anyway my problem was MSS size and solve with changing it in ip --> firewall. Thanks for share your idea with me. Regards

Comment: Yep, I realized that. I just stumbled upon this trouble-shooting method that I thought might benefit others who, like myself, are unfamiliar with RouterOS.